# How do I convert Exif long/lat to real values?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, latitude-longitude, exif

I am trying to get the Exif data from some of my pictures and these are the latitude and longitude values that I am receiving. Can someone help me out and tell me what these numbers mean?

DEBUG/lat = 30/1,12/1,34/1    (7588)   : lattitude

DEBUG/long = 81/1,22/1,41/1   (7588)  : longitude

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was going to write a converter for this and stuff, but it turns out the answer [is already in this blog](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/convert-exif-gps-info-to-degree-format.html)

Just in case if the link goes dead:

```
public class geoDegree {
private boolean valid = false;
Double Latitude, Longitude; 
geoDegree(ExifInterface exif) {
 String attrLATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
 String attrLATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
 String attrLONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
 String attrLONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);

 if((attrLATITUDE !=null)
   && (attrLATITUDE_REF !=null)
   && (attrLONGITUDE != null)
   && (attrLONGITUDE_REF !=null))
 {
  valid = true;

  if(attrLATITUDE_REF.equals("N")){
   Latitude = convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
  }
  else{
   Latitude = 0 - convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
  }

  if(attrLONGITUDE_REF.equals("E")){
   Longitude = convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
  }
  else{
   Longitude = 0 - convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
  }

 }
};

private Float convertToDegree(String stringDMS){
 Float result = null;
 String[] DMS = stringDMS.split(",", 3);

 String[] stringD = DMS[0].split("/", 2);
    Double D0 = new Double(stringD[0]);
    Double D1 = new Double(stringD[1]);
    Double FloatD = D0/D1;

 String[] stringM = DMS[1].split("/", 2);
 Double M0 = new Double(stringM[0]);
 Double M1 = new Double(stringM[1]);
 Double FloatM = M0/M1;

 String[] stringS = DMS[2].split("/", 2);
 Double S0 = new Double(stringS[0]);
 Double S1 = new Double(stringS[1]);
 Double FloatS = S0/S1;

    result = new Float(FloatD + (FloatM/60) + (FloatS/3600));

 return result;


};

public boolean isValid()
{
 return valid;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return (String.valueOf(Latitude)
   + ", "
   + String.valueOf(Longitude));
}

public int getLatitudeE6(){
 return (int)(Latitude*1000000);
}

public int getLongitudeE6(){
 return (int)(Longitude*1000000);
}

}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it converts, but the result always seems to be about 50 feet SW of where I expect.  Has anyone else found this?

Comment: @Craig - The original code used `float` (single precision) for Lat and Long which is not accurate enough - `float` is only good to about 7 digits of precision.  I modified it to be `double`.

Comment: Yup you should have changed it to double, plus  the getLongitudeE6 is wrong as well (correct me if i'm wrong), you should not multiply it by 1000000 if you return double instead of float