# Error when using setmarker() from an array to GPS map

Tags: android, arrays, google-maps, gps

I have an array of pictures which i extract the longitude and latitude details from using exif and put them on a marker on the GPS map. Currently i am using static array which i plan to change to a dynamic array in the near future. The current code crashes my app everytime i try to set my marker, i have no idea whats wrong.

```
public void setMarker() {
    double latitude, longitude;
    String[] filepath = {"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CapturyGallery/CapImage1451887532716.jpg", "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CapturyGallery/CapImage1452411474153.jpg"};
    ExifInterface intf = null;
    for (int y = 0; y < filepath.length; y++) {
        try {
            intf = new ExifInterface(filepath[y]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (intf != null) {
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE));
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE));
            LatLng latLngCurrent = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLngCurrent)
                    .title("test");
                mMap.addMarker(options);

        }


    }

}
```

**LOGCAT**

---

`

```
01-11 15:19:30.251  32226-32226/com.sp.fyp.captury E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sp.fyp.captury, PID: 32226
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4298)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4293)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1/1,18/1,30/1"
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
            at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
            at com.sp.fyp.captury.GPS.setMarker(GPS.java:181)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4293)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)`
```

Comment: you got any error message?

Comment: Share the crash logs to better understand the problem

Comment: Updated with crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Standard Exif Tags](http://exiv2.org/tags.html) (as defined in the Exif 2.3 standard)

> The latitude/longitude is expressed as three RATIONAL values giving
>   the degrees, minutes, and seconds, respectively. When degrees, minutes
>   and seconds are expressed, the format is dd/1,mm/1,ss/1. When degrees
>   and minutes are used and, for example, fractions of minutes are given
>   up to two decimal places, the format is dd/1,mmmm/100,0/1

Thus, when you get the latitude and logitude from the `ExifInterface`, you are getting values like `1/1,18/1,30/1`. Of course this `String` values cannot be converted to `double` using `Double.parseDouble` and throw a `NumberFormatException`.

You can take a look at [How do I convert Exif long/lat to real values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269462/how-do-i-convert-exif-long-lat-to-real-values) to find a converter.

Comment: Thanks! App was able to run smoothly